# Call a function from another class component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components

I would like to split my render into several parts.

There must be some code bits missing because my real code is more than a thousand lines, this one is for example.

Basically I would like to be able to call `Page2` and use the functions `handleSubmit` and `handleChange` in the `Page2`. But when i'm calling Page2, the code say he don't find the handleSubmit and the handleChange. I would like it to work as if I had not separated my code into several functions. If anyone have a idea :/

So I separated my code like this:

Page1.js :

```
  import {Page2} from './Page2';

  const initialState = { test:'', test2: ''};


  export default class Page1 extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = initialState;
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
           }
          handleChange(event) {
            const InputValue = event.target.value;
            const stateField = event.target.name;
            this.setState({
              [stateField]: InputValue,
            });
           console.log(this.state);
         }

         async handleSubmit(event) {
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            event.preventDefault();
            const { test= ''} = this.state;
            await axios.post(' (endpoint API)',
             { key1: `${test}`);
         }
       render() {
        return (
          <Tabs selectedIndex={this.state.tabIndex} onSelect={tabIndex => this.setState({ tabIndex })}>
            <TabList>
              <Tab >Non Dynamique</Tab>
              <Tab> Automation </Tab>
          </TabList>
          <TabPanel>
            <Input type="number" step="0.01" name="test" onChange={this.handleChange} value= 
               {this.state.test || ''}/> </Col>
           <Button type="submit"> Update </Button>
           </TabPanel>
           <TabPanel>
             {this.Page2}

           </TabPanel>
          );
      }
}
```

Page 2:

```
    export class Page2 extends Component {
     render() {
      return(
        <Input type="number" step="0.01" name="test2" onChange={this.handleChange} value= 
               {this.state.test || ''}/> </Col>
        <Button type="submit"> Update </Button>
           );
        }
      }
```

Thank you for any response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to render `page2` as react component and pass those function reference as props something like this.

```
<Page2 handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
```

In Page2 component you can get the above function reference in props.

```
export default class Page2 extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state= {

          }
         }

     render() {
       const { handleSubmit, handleChange} = this.props
      return(
        <div>
         <Input type="number" step="0.01" name="test2" onChange={handleChange} value= 
           {this.state.test || ''}/> 
         <Button type="submit" onSumbit={handleSubmit}> Update </Button>
       </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get error with this code : "Warning: The tag <Page2> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter." and "React does not recognize the `handleChange` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `handlechange` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.". I don't know if you have a idea why i have this weird errors

Comment: update you're page2 component name it is `render2`. React component, start its name with an uppercase letter

Comment: as you're using default export you can import like this in page1 component 
`import Page2 from './Page2';`

Comment: Yeah the render2 was a mistake of writing. But it was the uppercase the problem. I just replaced page2 in Page2 on the <Page2 handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} /> , and it's working. I'm gonna try to put this example to my code. But now i see who is working. So thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
<Page2 handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} test={this.state.test}/>
```

On Page2 code

```
export default  render2 = (props) => {
  return <div>
        <Input type="number" step="0.01" name="test2" onChange={props.handleChange} value= 
               {props.test || ''}/> </Col>
        <Button type="submit" handleSubmit={props.handleSubmit}> Update </Button>
</div>
};
```